# tikz pgf duplicate labels or node contents cause trouble with searching in a pdf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I have a script that creates tikzpicture in which some of the nodes have the same labels and creates a pdf. If my script creates two nodes in a row with the same label, even if they are located in very different parts of a graph, I will only find one of the two labels when I search the pdf. I've tried several different pdf viewers, and all have the same issue. However, if I insert a third node with a unique label or content between the two nodes, search works as expected.

The same thing happens if I have duplicate node contents, presumably because that's actually how labels work anyway. Also, note that naming the nodes differently doesn't matter.

For example, in this case, search will only find one of the two nodes:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0, 0) {A};
\node (b) at (3, -8) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The same will happen here, since the node in the middle has no contents:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0, 0) {A};
\node (c) at (0, 1) {};
\node (b) at (3, -8) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Even worse, the mere fact that the first node starts with an A means a search will not find the second node, despite the fact that their names are not the same.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0, 0) {AC};
\node (b) at (3, -8) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

while in this case, search will find each A individually.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0, 0) {A};
\node (c) at (0, 1) {B};
\node (b) at (3, -8) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result of \listpackages

```
 *File List*
  letter.cls    2014/09/29 v1.2z Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pgfplots.sty    2017/06/05 v1.15 Data Visualization (1.15)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2017/04/14 v1.1b Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2017/01/12 v0.06k Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.7)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
```

Right now I've got my script catching sequential nodes with the same labels and inserting invisible junk nodes between them. I'd like to keep things in alphabetical order for simplicity and to help me debug the generated tex file if something goes wrong. However, the invisible junk nodes still need to have printable characters, so that means a search might find them, and I'd rather that not happen. Also, the invisible junk nodes apparently need unique contents to work reliably.

Are there any other options than either having the script shuffle the nodes to make sure they aren't in alphabetical order or have it insert extra nodes that really shouldn't be needed? I don't even know if this is a tikz problem or a pdf problem, but since I'm using some other pdf features, I want to avoid switching document formats.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/49901) Sounds like this could be a pdf-viewer specific problem. Try with another viewer (for example (sumatra PDF)[https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html) if you are on windows)

Comment: I've tested it on Adobe Reader, OS X Preview, and just now on Chrome. The only one that seems to search correctly is Chrome, but Chrome doesn't handle tooltips or ocgs, both of which are kind of important. I'd also really rather not require someone to install an additional program just to read this one file.

Comment: Searching for `A` in the TexShop viewer, Mac Acrobat DC Reader and Mac Preview seems to work fine for me. I am using TeXLive 2017. If you are not on the latest release, please update or use `\listfiles` to list the version of your packages and post here so we can see if perhaps some of your packages are out of date.

Comment: Adding `\usepackage{cmap}` map help

Comment: I thought I updated everything in August, but apparently a couple of packages were still old. An update fixed the search in Preview, which can't handle ocgs, but not in Adobe Reader, which can.

Comment: You're compiling with pdfTeX? What happens if you don't load `pdfcomment`? I assume it is responsible for pulling in all those packages - would be good to know if the problem is not in them. Is this Mac TeX 2017? What version of Reader, to compare with @PeterGrill? ( I guess you aren't bothered about Linux compatibility, since you're relying on Reader.)

Comment: Removing pdfcomment didn't change anything. I'm not even sure why I included it in the test file, since it was actually the first thing I tried removing when I started hunting for the problem. I'm using the pdfTeX from MacPorts. I'm not sure what the version of Reader is, since it's on a campus computer. It probably isn't the newest version, but it's probably from within the last few months. I figure anybody running Linux can either find another PDF viewer that can handle ocgs or can figure out how to run Reader with wine.